# preg_match_all multiple pattern leaves empty array values

Tags: php, arrays, pattern-matching, preg-match-all

I am trying to understand `preg_match_all` with multiple patterns inside it, so I created html string variable and pattern.

Everything like trimming works fine but it outputs some array keys with empty values because of multiple pattern. If you know why it makes like this please tell me and also show me how it must be fixed.

My Code:

```
<?php
        $cource = "<div><a href='test1'>  <img src=\"test2\" /> <img src='test3' > <script src='test4'> <link href='test5'> </div>";

        preg_match_all('/src=["\']([^"\']+)|href=\'([^\']+)/',$cource, $result); 

        var_dump($result);
?>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That regex is not valid, are you sure this is the pattern you're using?

Comment: Sorry i i edited it, now it is correct

Comment: That's how the output is supposed to be structured. You get one array per `(…)` capture group - and only the matched one will be populated each. Rather condense the alternatives with a no-capture group `(?:x=|y=)`

Comment: thanks for answer mario, can you show me how no-capture group pattern must look like for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting empty values cause of using two capturing groups,

- 1st is for `src`
- 2nd is for `href`

hence you are getting empty values as per your data as first element has attribute `href` you got `src` blank (as it doesn't have it) so on and so forth.

You can grab results in one capture (second) group, first one is left for references for what attributes it's taken from.

```
$cource = "<div><a href='test1'>  <img src=\"test2\" /> <img src='test3' > <script src='test4'> <link href='test5'> </div>";

preg_match_all('/(href|src)=["\']([^"\']+)/',$cource, $result);
```

In case you don't need reference attributes, you can use non capturing group `?:`

```
preg_match_all('/(?:href|src)=["\']([^"\']+)/',$cource, $result);
```

In Action: https://eval.in/580585

Comment: @Dest you are welcome, check it out for explanation on why are you getting blank values, I've updated my answer